# Which one is correct {in or on}?

Tags: prepositions

1} You were late **in** telling us the
truth.

Or

2} You were late **on** telling us the
truth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is late or early **in** *doing something*.

> You are late doing something:
>
> They were late paying the rent.
>
> You can also say that someone is **late in** doing something:
>
> They were **late in** paying the rent.

[Late (Longman Dictionary)](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/late)